# Possible to set a contact as the default for a particular email

Tags: civimail, duplicate-contacts

I'm not even certain how best to ask this question. Here's the situation:
Staff people at an org I support often wind up accidentally creating duplicates of themselves during event testing in Civi but with incorrect or empty name fields (and other fields).

Whatever system Civi uses to de-duplicate emails, these empty records often wind up being the ones that get selected when emails go out which leads to folks receiving "customized" emails with empty data where a token fails because there is nothing in the name field. This also sometimes happens for non-staff records if we import a list from somewhere else that has no names but duplicates an existing email. Obviously we want to reduce and eliminate duplicates, but we can't necessarily take time to do that before every email.

I'm wondering if there is some way to manage priority when CiviCRM is doing its de-duplication during a mailing to ensure that our "canonical" record comes up rather than some recent import or unwisely created duplicate without good data. Is it possible to get it to always favour the lowest value CID, or something like that?

Comment: I saw a comment recently about a Job that could rerun the default bulk duplicate merging - wondering whether you need something like that running on your system

Comment: That would certainly help limit the problem. I'll see if I can turn up that note. Was it here on StackExchange?

Comment: actually i can't find it - thought it was a discussion on MM - if you post there I will @ the person i thought mentioned it